# How to get the recently added values from database to Autocomplete Textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

How can i get the recently added values from my database to my textbox (with Autosuggest) I need to exit the application just to see the recently added values to my textbox. I hope someone would be able to help me in this matter.

```
 public void AutoSuggest()
    {
        List<string> col = new List<string>();
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select Codeitem from employee_product", con))
            {

                using (var reader = select.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        col.Add(reader["Codeitem"].ToString());
                    }                        
                    txt_code.AutoCompleteMode           = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    txt_code.AutoCompleteSource         = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                    txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
                    txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(col.ToArray());
                    AddingProduct();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
This Image is for adding my product and you can see the recently added product the selected one.

[image]
This image is for getting the code value of my product. You can see when i tried to input the code, he can't suggest the recently added

Comment: Basically you need to reload the AutoCompleteCustomSource   of the text box after adding new product. So call the method AutoSuggest() at the end of btn_add_Click handler method.

Comment: @Saran Doesn't work, and it doesn't add anymore after doing that

Comment: Have you set `txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;` somewhere (and verified that the collection contains what you're expecting)? Also, assign the `.AutoCompleteCustomSource` after you have specified the auto complete behaviour (`.AutoCompleteSource` and `.AutoCompleteMode`).

Comment: @Jimi I don't understand you , but i understand this (and verified that the collection contains what you're expecting).. Yes I'm getting the correct collection of values :)

Comment: What is not clear? Did you set the `.AutoCompleteSource` property to `AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource`? When you do, remember that assigning a value to the `.AutoCompleteCustomSource` property is the last thing you do, not the first. Assing the other properties as described first.

Comment: @Jimi What did you mean to this "assigning a value to the .AutoCompleteCustomSource property is the last thing you do" ? , Yes of course i set it to customsource :)

Comment: Where? In your code, you have `txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;` `txt_code.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;`. `txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;` is missing and `txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;` should be the last assignment (after the other two properties).

Comment: @Jimi i added it but still, doesn't solve my problem, you just correct it

Comment: Show the updated code. Also, try using a `List<string>` instead of a `AutoCompleteStringCollection`. Declare it outside any `using` block: (`List<string> MyCollection = new List<string>();`), add the string elements the same way, then (outside the `using` block) write: `txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear(); txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(MyCollection.ToArray());`

Comment: @Jimi Already update but it still doesnt solve, btw i'm using a tab

Comment: Well, this is how you add a custom Autocomplete source. If inspecting the `txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource`, right after it has been filled, reveals that it contains the expected items, then there's something not shown here that resets it (or you add the TextBox as a `new` control or is not the same control or...). Debug it following it with a `Watch`.

Comment: @Jimi , Thank you for cleaning my code. I already Fix it i just paste my method on click event of my tab :)